# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «er»

Tags: java, postgresql

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT sum(cast(er.num_importe as float)),r.entidad,r.referencia,r.moneda_id "
                + "from EnvioRemesa er "
                + "inner join Remesa r"
                + "on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id "
                + "where r.envio_remesa_id = 3 and r.tipo_doc='101' "
                + "GROUP BY entidad,referencia,r.moneda_id ORDER BY entidad ASC");
```

Buenas, estoy usando Postgresql como BD, y estoy intentando realizar esta consulta, pero me salta el error este , no sé por qué.He probado también con AS para asignar el alia

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «er»
```

Comment: Si te fijas las lineas "inner join Remesa r" y "on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id" van a acabar concatenadas como "Remesa ron er.id = r.envio_remesa_id".  Añade un espacio en esa línea de forma que quede "inner join Remesa r ".

Comment: ¿Con mi sugerencia se corrigió tu error o sigue produciéndose?